# pulseaudio-dlna not working with mpd and ROCKI devices

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, dlna, mpd

Note: I rewrote this question because the signal-to-noise ratio was approaching 0.

Just installed pulseaudio-dnla on my Ubuntu 14.04.2 system to create pulse sinks for my ROCKIs so I can stream audio to any of my ROCKIs, hopefully choosing which of the ROCKIs to stream to from within mpd.

Pulseaudio-dlna is working great my ROCKIs and VLC - I can select any of my 3 ROCKIs as the VLC Audio Device *by name*, and pulsaudio-dlna sends the audio to that ROCKI.  Couldn't be easier.

But I'm having trouble making it work mpd.  I got past the user-space/system-wide pulseaudio/mpd issue by running mpd in user-space.  I can get it to send audio to one device using padevchooser (as Massimo suggested below).  But when I try to make an output for each ROCKI using the same sink names that work for VLC:

```
audio_output {
    type        "pulse"
    name        "rockigreen"
}

audio_output {
    type        "pulse"
    name        "rockigarage"
}
```

...no sound comes out of my ROCKIs.

Comment: AFAIK the ROKI device should be supported. Some issues were fixed in the [development branch](https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna/tree/refactor/streaming-server) but are not yet available through the PPA, nevertheless worth to try out. In case the issues persist it may be worth contacting the developer @Massimo through the [project's bug tracking](https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna/issues) - to my experience he is very helpful. You can also try with different codecs that may work better on some devices.

Comment: I just rewrote the question with a lot more detail.  Been talking to Massimo, but I don't think the fault is with pulseaudio-dlna, I think it's in the info mpd supplies to the output when it opens it.  Or something.  :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the "sink" field in the audio_output section of.mpdconf.  I mistakenly thought mpd used the "name" field to select which pulseaudio sink to use, so I set "name" to the pulseaudio name (i.e. "rockigreen").  In actuality, mpd's "name" field is just the label used for the output.  However if you put the pulseaudio "name" in the .mpdconf "sink" field, mpd sends audio to the sink of that name.

(You could also use the pulse audio sink index (0 or 1 or 2, etc..), but the sink index can change with reboots and device disconnects/reconnects, so the pulse audio "name" is a better choice.)

The following section of my .mpdconfig file allows me to select, via any mpd client software, any or all of the 3 pulse sinks, by whatever label I choose:

```
audio_output {
    type        "pulse"
    name        "My A/V Receiver (via pulse)"
    sink        "alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-surround-extra2"
}

audio_output {
    type        "pulse"
    name        "The Rocki In My Bedroom"
    sink        "rockigreen"
}

audio_output {
    type        "pulse"
    name        "The Rocki In My Garage"
    sink        "rockigarage"
}
```

I'm running pulse, pulseaudio-dlna, and mpd as the current user (me).  As Massimo notes in his comment, this may not work or may require fancy user/group permission changes if you're not doing the same.

Comment: And this works with *pulseaudio-dlna*? I did some experiments myself and you should mention, that you need have to run *mpd* as your current user, not as *mpd* or root. Since *pulseaudio* runs also as your current user this is necessary, otherwise *mpd* won't be able to access those sinks.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following again and it works on another computer without any issues. Perhaps you did not restart mpd after you inserted the TCP module into *pulseaudio*. Or perhaps you did not enable the 2nd output.

Change your 2nd output in your *mpd.conf* to:

```
audio_output {
    type            "pulse"
    name            "MPD Pulse Output"
    server          "localhost"
}
```

Insert the TCP module to *pulseaudio*:

```
pactl load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1
```

Restart mpd:

```
sudo service mpd restart
```

Install mpc to check the outputs:

```
sudo apt-get install mpc
mpc outputs
```

Make sure the correct output is enabled:

```
mpc enable <number-of-your-output>
```

Play a song, *pulseaudio* should now be aware of the mpd stream, so you can switch it via *pavucontrol* or the ubuntu sound settings to play on your device.

Comment: That does not work for me.  My system may have a problem with localhost - when I was setting up mythtv I had to replace localhost with the fixed IP of my machine in several places to get it to work.  When I do exactly what you say, mpc shows two outputs ("My ALSA Device" [which works] and "MPD Pulse Output" [which doesn't]).  I don't understand how mpd is to differentiate between multiple ROCKIs with this technique, unless I'm supposed to replace "MPD Pulse Output" with each ROCKI name discovered by pulseaudio-dlna (tried that, too - didn't work).  Something is hosed in my pa/mpd install.

Comment: Of course I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling pa and mpd but that didn't change anything...  And I reboot often after I make a change just in case something is still running (though I don't think there is).

Comment: Could you paste your */etc/hosts* somewhere? Whats about changing your 2nd host to *server          "127.0.0.1"*?

Comment: Pasted /etc/hosts to bottom of message.  Honestly not sure what 'changing your 2nd host to server "127.0.0.1"' means/entails.

Comment: Looking at the pulseaudio-dlna log files for VLC and mpd, they both start with "new_playback_stream", but mpd never gets to the "device_updated" state.   What could mpd not be doing that causes it to start opening the sink but then not take the next step?

Comment: Your */etc/hosts* file looks fine. To answer your questions:  Normally every application sends its audio to *pulseaudio* and therefore you can switch the stream to a virtual *sink* generate by *pulseaudio-dlna*. Unfortunately you choosed one of the bare applications which are capable of using other sound servers besides *pulseaudio*.  So, our goal is to make *mpd* send its audio stream also to *pulseaudio* regardless on which ROCKI device you want to play.

Comment: From that point you can choose with *pavucontrol* to which ROCKI device you actually want to stream, thats how you differentiate between different devices. *pulseaudio* acts like a sound proxy, actually thats what its made for. I meant with changing your 2nd host to server "127.0.0.1" that you replace the host "localhost" in your *mpd.conf* with "127.0.0.1". So that you end up with the line *server          "127.0.0.1"* instead of *server          "localhost"*

Comment: Ahhh....now I get what you're saying.  Yes, following those instructions I can get sound to pulseaudio and choose the output with pavucontrol.  I didn't get that far before because I didn't understand that I needed to select the output with pavucontrol...

Comment: Thanks again for your help, Massimo.  

However I really want to use my mpd clients to choose the audio, so I can select which speakers (i.e. outputs, i.e. pulse sinks)  are on and off from the same app I use to select and control the music.  I'm pretty certain this can be done because 1) I did have it working for one glorious 5 minute period, and 2) VLC has no problem directly sending music to whichever dlna/upnp devices discovered by pulseaudio-dlna that it wants, and it does it using that device's name.  So I'm continuing my quest to make that work again!